# How to explain density() plots in R?

Tags: r, density-function

I am doing spectrum analysis. For two given bands, I find out the percentage utilization. I have percentage utilization on the x-axis and the estimated pdf on y-axis.

To make you follow how I got these plots

> I load the measurement files which have the energy values
>   then I find the duty cycle per row as (I sweep once and then see how much spectrum is used) x<- apply(data, 1, duty_cycle, threshold)
>   and then I plot using plot(density(100*x)) so I get the % on the x axis.

SO the basic interpretation would be the maximum utilization is 40 %, although how is the y axis related.

How do I interpret the y-axis?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hint: what is the area under each curve?

Answer (score 2):

I always describe the "density" output as a "smooth histogram". The y-axis can't tell you much for a given point except a possible estimate of the continuous mode. The y-axis allows you to estimate event probabilities using the volume of the curve over certain regions. If you summed up the area (or integrated) between two values, you would arrive at an estimate of the probability of sampling a value between those two values in an independent replication of the data collection.

Comment: @Sp7577 "the data appear to be bimodal"

Comment: @Sp7577 you could only rank the two modes.

Comment: @Sp7577 I already have: if you're familiar with a prob density, the y-axis is arbitrary and scale dependent. To obtain raw probabilities you must integrate. The issue of modal estimation in continuous dfs is not well explored.